# Convert superscripted numbers from string into scientific notation (from Unicode, UTF8)

Tags: r, superscript

I imported a vector of p-values from an Excel table. The numbers are given as superscripted Unicode strings. After hours of trying I still struggle to convert them into numbers.

See example below. Simple conversion with `as.numeric()` doesn't work. I also tried to use Regex to capture the superscripted numbers, but it turned out that each superscripted number has a distinct Unicode code, for which there is no translation.

```
test <- c("0.0126", "0.000289", "4.26x10⁻¹⁴", "6.36x10⁻⁴⁸", 
          "4.35x10⁻⁹", "0.115", "0.0982", "0.000187", "0.0484", "0.000223")

as.numeric(test)
```

Does somebody know of an R-package which could do the translation painlessly, or do I have to translate the codes one by one into digits?

Comment: It may be easier to fix on the import. What function are you using to import the excel data? Also, in excel, are the p-values stored as text with the unicode characters or is it a column with scientific notation?

Comment: How did you import the data? Looks like the code imported the formatted text, not the numeric data. Excel stores numeric data is stored as numbers, not text. What users see is the effect of styling.

Comment: On the other hand if whoever created the Excel sheet wrote the string `6.36x10⁻⁴⁸` in a cell, there's not a lot you can do except parse that string eg with a regular expression, extract the superscripts and create a multiplier. Excel would display `6.365E-43`, not `6.36x10⁻⁴⁸`. You should probably ask whoever created this sheet to remove fancy formatting

Comment: Yeah, someone has put quite some effort into creating this fancy excel table (it's a supplementary table of a large published GWAS from Nature Genetics). I cannot do too much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of formatting is definitely not very portable... Here's one possible solution though, for the exercise...

```
test <- c("0.0126", "0.000289", "4.26x10⁻¹⁴", "6.36x10⁻⁴⁸",
          "4.35x10⁻⁹", "0.115", "0.0982", "0.000187", "0.0484",
          "0.000223")

library(utf8)
library(stringr)

# normalize, ie everything to "normal text"
testnorm <- utf8_normalize(test, map_case = TRUE, map_compat = TRUE)

# replace exponent part
# \\N{Minus Sign} is the unicode name of the minus sign symbol
# (see [ICU regex](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp))
# it is necessary because the "-" is not a plain text minus sign...
testnorm <- str_replace_all(testnorm, "x10\\N{Minus Sign}", "e-")

# evaluate these character strings
p_vals <- sapply(X = testnorm,
                    FUN = function(x) eval(parse(text = x)),
                    USE.NAMES = FALSE
)

# everything got adjusted to the "e-48" element...
format(p_vals, digits = 2, scientific = F)
```

Comment: I think you've solved my problem, thank you! The function uft8_normalize() was the key step from the utf8 library.